# How to quote all variable names with a regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"xyz([x,3],x,[x,y],{y:1})" needs to be "xyz(['x',3],'x',['x','y'],{'y':1})"
```

**Note**: Variables can be in this case any letter from `a` to `z`

I need to replace variables like x, y and z with their quoted versions

In my test the comma is being captured by the regex, the problem is that if I capture x then y is not captured because of the intersecting comma.

```
var str = "xyz([x,3],x,[x,y],{y:1})"
str.replace(/(\W)([a-z])(\W)/g,"$1'$2'$3")
//output: mul(['x',3],'x',['x',y],{'y':1})
```

Added example: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wy1wrzhz/1/)

Is there a way to specify the surrounding elements without capturing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace the variable before comma or colon.

```
    var txt="xyz([x,3],x,[x,y],{y:1})";

    txt.replace(/[a-z]+[,:\])]/g, function f(x){
       return "'"+x.replace(/[,:\]\)]/g,"")+"'"+x[x.length-1];
   })
```

Comment: ok but what about all the other elements like ) or ], The thing is that it needs to be any variable name in the parameters I just added a few variations

Comment: but I guess you are right, maybe the best solution is to add cases as they appear

Comment: ok man, but I think `*` should be `+`. `*` will match anything from 0 characters and to catch y you should also add `[,:\])]` https://jsfiddle.net/wy1wrzhz/3/

Answer (score -1):

You are adding capture groups with that are creating issues. Remove them and use:

```
\W([a-z])\W
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/TXCWcU/1) is a working version.

**Update**

Working with your js,

```
var original = "xyz([x,3],x,[x,y],{y:1})"
var replaced = original.replace(/([a-z])/g, "'$1'")
```

and I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: ok I added an example to better illustrate the problem https://jsfiddle.net/wy1wrzhz/

Comment: You could be right except that you can find a letter from a-z in the function name or anywhere else https://jsfiddle.net/wy1wrzhz/2/